# Wireless link is blinking continuously even when I am using wired connection

Tags: 12.04, intel-wireless

My laptop wireless is blinking continuously even when I am using wired connection. I disabled the wireless but it's not working.

- IBM t42
- 1 GB RAM
- 1.7 GHz Intel processor
- Inter Pro wireless card

Comment: Can you post the outputs of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` from a terminal window.

Comment: Some Intel wireless cards are know for ennoying blinking, but, as far as I know, 3945AGN, 4965AGN (and likely others) have a module optiion to disable the blinking. Just need to know which module is in use.

Answer (score 0):

If the wireless is just not "connected" you can, depending on lots of things, still see activity when it probes for available access points.

A simple solution is:

```
:~$ rfkill list  
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
:~$ rfkill block 1
```

To re-enable wireless:

```
:~$ rfkill unblock 1
```

I seriously doubt "my computer is slow" is related to wireless directly.  More likely an under-powered graphics card pushing unity.

This is tested with an Intel Pro 5100 AGN.